# What exactly is kg?

Tags: mass, definition, si-units, metrology

[Kilogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilogram) literally makes no sense. We say that we are 10 kilogram by using the weighing scale but according to its definition, it is the amount of matter contained in an object. So how much matter is a kilogram and also it feels wrong. For example we say that some amount of tungsten is 10 kg and we also say that a human child is 10 kg. Clearly the human child has way more atoms so shouldn't it be different or something.

Edit (july 7 2023):
So kg was defined as some physical thing but now it is replaced with an equation which defines what a kilogram is using constants? Am i right?

Comment: you should start here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilogram

Comment: I think the question should be really about *mass* rather than it unit.

Answer (score 2):

> according to its definition, it is the amount of matter contained in an object.

This is incorrect. The actual definition of the kilogram is

> The kilogram, symbol $\mathrm{kg}$, is the SI unit of mass. It is defined by taking the fixed numerical value of the Planck constant $h$ to be $6.62607015×10^{-34}$ when expressed in the unit $\mathrm{J⋅s}$, which is equal to $\mathrm{kg⋅m^2⋅s^{−1}}$, where the metre and the second are defined in terms of $c$ and $Δν_{Cs}$.

Nowhere in the definition of the kilogram does it speak of the amount of matter.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Guess my textbook is wrong. In the text it is literally given as Mass is the amount of substance in a body while weight is the force of g acting on a given mass. Also can you simplify the definition of kilogram for me cause, we use an actual physical object which says how much mass is?

Answer (score 1):

According to NIST

> For more than a century, the kilogram (kg) — the fundamental unit of mass in the International System of Units (SI) — was defined as exactly equal to the mass of a small polished cylinder, cast in 1879 of platinum and iridium.

Actually 1 kg is equal to another standard weight and in a sense not a fundamental quantity.

Every atom has different mass that roughly equals to sum of mass of neutron and protons in it. Also the mass of a neutron and proton is roughly the same.

So roughly speaking 10 kg of tungsten has almost the same total neutrons and protons as that of human child.

Yes number of atoms in human child are more because humans are mostly made of light atoms such as hydrogen oxygen and carbon having atomic weights ~2, 16 and 12. On the other hand tungsten has atomic weight ~184. Atomic weight is roughly equal to the sum of the number of protons and neutrons in an atom.

I hope it cleared your doubts a little.

Answer (score 0):

Mass is what a balance, one of the fundamental instruments of physics, measures. The kilogram is the SI unit of mass.

A count of atoms is a different measure of the quantity of matter. Chemists use a scaled version of this: the [mole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_(unit)). For the purposes of chemistry, knowing how many moles of substance you have is often more important than how many kilograms.

But for physics, most models depend on mass rather than count of atoms. For example, when we compute orbits, the masses of the bodies are important, but the number of moles of matter isn't. Mass is intimately connected to energy, another important concept, by the famous relation $E=mc^2$.